# how can i search value in Array?

Tags: php

I have an array like this and i m trying to search a value 
using this array:

```
$arr = Array('Slovenly Mexico','Slovenly Europe','Greece');
```

I am using such kind of condition. please help

```
if($a[storename] == $arr[$i]){
                //some code

          }
```

but it is not working because it searches as index value so it gives an error.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (                    
            [storename] => Greece
        )

    [1] => Array
        (         
            [storename] => Slovenly Europe
        )


    [3] => Array
        (           
            [storename] => Slovenly Europe
        )

    [4] => Array
        (       
           [storename] => Greece
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
        [storename] => Slovenly Mexico

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [storename] => Slovenly Europe
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
         [storename] => Slovenly Mexico

        )
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use in_array()

eg.,

```
$sizeofarray=sizeof($a);
for($i=0;$i<sizeofarray;$i++)
{
   if(in_array($a[$i][storename],$arr)) 
   {
       echo "Found";
       break;
   }
   else
       echo "Not found";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
in_array($a[storename], $arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

you  can search value using array bu

> ***A.*** [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) — Checks if a value exists in an array .`in_array` return  Boolean value

```
<?php
 $os = array("one", "two", "three", "four");
 if (in_array("two", $os)) {
    echo "Got two";
 }
 if (in_array("one", $os)) {
    echo "Got one";
 }
?>
```

> ***B.***  you can also use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful

```
<?php
 $array = array(0 => 'one', 1 => 'two', 2 => 'three', 3 => 'four');

 $key = array_search('one', $array); // $key = 0;
 $key = array_search('four', $array);   // $key = 3;
 ?>
```

for further reference [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)